# Why isn't my Python regex matching part of the query string?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, url

I'm using Python 3.7.  I want to extract the portion of a url between the "q=...&" part of a query string.  I have this code

```
    href = span.a['href']
    print("href:" + href)
    matchObj = re.match( r'q=(.*?)\&', href, re.M|re.I)
    if matchObj:
        criteria = matchObj.group(1)
```

but despite the fact that my href is this

```
href:/search?hl=en-US&q=bet+i+won+t+get+one+share&tbm=isch&tbs=simg:CAQSkwEJyapBtj9kKiIahwELEKjU2AQaAAwLELCMpwgaYgpgCAMSKMILxAufFcsLnBWeFZsVnRWABMcPsCKgLaMtoi2hLZ0tqziiI6w4uSQaMG01mL5LQ62s4q5ZMf-Wetz68lCkHfrFOOKs2CELzQJlPjHIMzmlp2Ny-a5t7hZbiCAEDAsQjq7-CBoKCggIARIEXLNODAw&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjThcCx59ziAhWKHLkGHfWjDs4Q2A4ILCgB
```

the "matchObj" is always NoneType and the subsequent lines aren't evaluated.  What else do I need to do to fix my regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `urllib` module

**Ex:**

```
import urllib.parse as urlparse
url = "href:/search?hl=en-US&q=bet+i+won+t+get+one+share&tbm=isch&tbs=simg:CAQSkwEJyapBtj9kKiIahwELEKjU2AQaAAwLELCMpwgaYgpgCAMSKMILxAufFcsLnBWeFZsVnRWABMcPsCKgLaMtoi2hLZ0tqziiI6w4uSQaMG01mL5LQ62s4q5ZMf-Wetz68lCkHfrFOOKs2CELzQJlPjHIMzmlp2Ny-a5t7hZbiCAEDAsQjq7-CBoKCggIARIEXLNODAw&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjThcCx59ziAhWKHLkGHfWjDs4Q2A4ILCgB"
data = urlparse.urlparse(url)
print(urlparse.parse_qs(data.query)['q'][0])
```

**Output:**

```
bet i won t get one share
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong function if you wish to match in the middle of the string.
[re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) only matches from start of the string

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the
>   regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object.

Here use [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match) instead.

```
import re
href = 'href:/search?hl=en-US&q=bet+i+won+t+get+one+share&tbm=isch&tbs=simg:CAQSkwEJyapBtj9kKiIahwELEKjU2AQaAAwLELCMpwgaYgpgCAMSKMILxAufFcsLnBWeFZsVnRWABMcPsCKgLaMtoi2hLZ0tqziiI6w4uSQaMG01mL5LQ62s4q5ZMf-Wetz68lCkHfrFOOKs2CELzQJlPjHIMzmlp2Ny-a5t7hZbiCAEDAsQjq7-CBoKCggIARIEXLNODAw&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjThcCx59ziAhWKHLkGHfWjDs4Q2A4ILCgB'
print("href:" + href)
matchObj = re.search( r'q=(.*?)\&', href, re.M|re.I)
if matchObj:
    criteria = matchObj.group(1)
print(criteria)
'bet+i+won+t+get+one+share'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, we would apply a simple expression with left and right boundaries such as:

```
&q=(.+?)&
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vpV8Kn/1/)

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"&q=(.+?)&"

test_str = "href:/search?hl=en-US&q=bet+i+won+t+get+one+share&tbm=isch&tbs=simg:CAQSkwEJyapBtj9kKiIahwELEKjU2AQaAAwLELCMpwgaYgpgCAMSKMILxAufFcsLnBWeFZsVnRWABMcPsCKgLaMtoi2hLZ0tqziiI6w4uSQaMG01mL5LQ62s4q5ZMf-Wetz68lCkHfrFOOKs2CELzQJlPjHIMzmlp2Ny-a5t7hZbiCAEDAsQjq7-CBoKCggIARIEXLNODAw&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjThcCx59ziAhWKHLkGHfWjDs4Q2A4ILCgB

"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]